# What side of the axes to compute in a solid of revolution question and how to model a question

Tags: integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

I'm a bit confused regarding questions involving solids of revolution.

For example, a question involves a polynomal, say, $x^2+2$ is rotated about the y-axis, find the volume for the solid of revolution between $x=1$ and $x=3$.

Suppose I use the shell method, and my equation becomes:

$V=2\pi\int^3_1(x)(x^2+2) dx$

This volume would include whatever is between the curve and the x-axis, rotated about the y-axis.

However, if I were to use the disk method, my equation becomes:

$V=\pi\int^{11}_{3}(\sqrt{(y-2)})^2 dy$

But, in order for both regions to have the same volume, the equations would need to be:

$V=2\pi\int^3_1(x)(11-(x^2+2)) dx$

and

$V=\pi\int^{11}_{3}(\sqrt{(y-2)})^2-(1)^2 dy$

I was wondering if someone could clarify the reasoning behind this. Also, if it's rotated about the y-axis, does that mean the volume is between the curve and the y-axis, and the same if it's rotated about the x-axis?

Thanks.

Comment: if you make a sketch, it would be more clear to you how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Note that the range for $x$ is from 1 to 3. So, the cross section evolving around $y$ is enclosed by $x>1$, $y<11$ and above the curve.

The shell integral is, then,

$$ V=2\pi \int_1^3 x[y(3)-y(x)] dx = 2\pi\int_1^3 x[11-(x^2+2)] dx$$

The integral for the disk, actually a disk ring with inner radius at 1, is

$$ V= \pi \int_3^{11} [x^2(y)-1] dy = \pi\int_3^{11} (y-3)dy$$

They come out the same at $32\pi$.